# Replace everything in the circuit except the 3 A source by its Thevenin equivalent circuit and use the result to find V1

Tags: circuit-analysis, electrical, thevenin

[image: circuit diagram]

Replace everything in the circuit except the 3 A source by its
Thevenin equivalent circuit and use the result to find V1.

This is my solution but the teacher said it is wrong and i do not know how to fix it.

[image: attempted solution image]

[image: attempted solution image 2]

Comment: Can you show "original" circuit without any "transformations"?

Comment: I'm glad you posted your work but is everything posted relevant? Or are the pages on the wrong order? Or what? Because I can't seem to follow.

Comment: @DKNguyen the first page is at the bottom then the second is the middle and third is first.

Comment: If this is your original circuit https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnRr6.png Then how can you end up with a bridge circuit?

Comment: I reordered it for you.

Comment: In the original schematic, is that a 24V source or a 24A source? The symbol does not match the label. I would interpret that symbol as a current source but its possible that someone might use that as a voltage source considering you have a different symbol for the 3A current source. Some people use an arrow to represent a rise in potential between two points but I've never seen someone stick it into a symbol and try to call it a voltage source because it is confusing. You interpreted as a current source in your work, but if its supposed to be a voltage source then the mistake is right there.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ohh okay,so the 24V is a voltage source.Thank you!

Comment: @AliceAt. You are only asking about Q1 right? If so, delete the last page and maybe crop the middle image since it's irrelevant.

Comment: @DKNguyen oh yes, i didnt see i uploaded question 2 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the original schematic, is that a 24V source or a 24A source? The symbol does not match the label. I would interpret that symbol as a current source but it is possible that someone might use that as a voltage source considering you have a different symbol for the 3A current source.

Some people use an arrow to represent a rise in potential between two points on a schematic but I've never seen someone try to stick the arrow into a component symbol and try to call it a voltage source because it is confusing.

You interpreted it as a current source in your work, but if it is supposed to be a voltage source then the mistake is right there. Not that it's your fault. That's a really bad symbol.